# alphanumeric arithmetic on postcodes

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I need to compare postcodes, given a range of possible postcodes, `string.Compare` works in my initial tests, but is there something that may go wrong with this approach? I initially thought to make a 'postcode walker' that produces ALL possible postcode and then I can check 'the set of all postcodes', but I'm concerned that would use a bunch of memory unnecessarily if I can use use string.Compare or something similar. Or are there any reliable 3rd party libraries that may support string arithmetic?

Here is my unit test to illustrate my requirement , this test works

```
[TestMethod]
public void ComparePostcode()
{
    var startPostcode = "RF7 2AA";
    var endPostcode   = "RF7 2ZZ";

    var postcodeToCompare = "RF7 2RX";  // is this postcode 'between' the other two?

    int startResult = string.Compare(startPostcode, postcodeToCompare);
    int endResult = string.Compare(endPostcode, postcodeToCompare);

    Assert.AreEqual(startResult, -1);
    Assert.AreEqual(endResult, 1);
}
```

I will be "`Trim()`"ing the strings, and removing all whitespace, and I don't think special characters are needed  (though it will need to work on all sorts of postcode/zipcodes eventually)

Edit: Initially, it will be UK postcodes

Edit: the pattern shown in my unit test is how parcel services describe postcode ranges that affect their price. I'll need to support other types of postcodes but the way they describe the range is pretty standard I think.

Comment: Wich countries postcode System is that? It is required taht we know the underlying rules. | It kinda looks like the UK one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom But it is important we are sure. Also a definition of how to Postcodes can be "between" one another.

Comment: Based on the Formating, do you want to look if Area, District and Sector match. While treating the Unit as a range of values you can sort/compare on? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Formatting | As a general rule, Postcodes due to being historically grown and subject to changes, usually do not follow a logical pattern. | They are best treated like a compound primary key. That can change, albeit slowly.

Comment: Only last two characters are different in start and end postcodes. Does it mean that `AA` is low and `ZZ` is high?  What issue you are facing with current code?

Comment: Another way of apparently expressing the same thing is to ask "do these postcodes share the same *prefix*?". The Royal Mail I believe also provide a regex to validate postcodes in terms of their structure and plausibility, although the only definitive validation is to refer to a current list of valid postcodes.

Comment: @Chetan, yes those are lows and highs, and the issues are being highlighted by Christopher I think, although the pattern I've shown is all I've got to go on, it's how parcel services and the like describe post code areas that they'll charge more for etc etc

Comment: @Christopher, your questions are interesting and it's kinda the point of why I'm asking, requirements are pretty vague as parcel services just give examples (like above), but think they keep the ranges short and simple because of the issues you are asking about?

Comment: @Ninjanoel: "but think they keep the ranges short and simple because of the issues you are asking about?" If anything, they do the opposite. They need room to adapt to stuff: "A postcode unit generally represents a street, part of a street, a single address, a group of properties, a single property, a sub-section of the property, an individual organisation or (for instance Driver and Vehicle Licensing Agency) a subsection of the organisation. The level of discrimination is often based on the amount of mail received by the premises or business." This is load adaptation.

Comment: As your question is about guesstimating the price of a Parcel Service, we would need to know their rules for "postcode ranges"/Price Selection.

Comment: You have to supply a sorting rule, you tend to say you maybe not satisfied with string-sorting. You supply code, say the code works, so what's the question ?
For your idea of "postcode" in other countries: You imagine it as the ID of a location, the cities are numbered. That's it. There is nothing encoded in it. GPS and Distance information can be referred by some algorithms. Also: Are there countries with pricing dependent on distance ?  I don't know any cause the distance is not an important factor in the costs at all. Handling is costly,Space and Weight.

Comment: @Holger The one thing that is usually priced based on distance is Public Transportation. Maybe this specific parcel Service has a similar scheme, for some reason? Hard to say without details.

Comment: I just say: This is not usual. This is exceptional. Prices go up with the size or weight of the parcel, not with distance. That starts if you go abroad, but international traffic is not covered with zip-codes. And I just mention, cause the OP wanted to cover 'other parcel services' later, and also came up with the idea of distance.

Comment: You are not making the comparison rules clear in your explanation. Do just the first three digits have to match? All but the last two? Different types of postcodes? Like American zip codes? Those are 5-digit numeric. I think you need to rework your question, the above comments show people are confused.

Comment: Op did not mention distance. Look this isn't an exam question or anything, this is real world, ranges are given, I've seen two seperate companies quote as I have mention, sometimes it's numbers, those are easier, maybe. This conversation is interesting but anyone wanna sum up an answer. Here is [ONE](https://www.dhl.com/content/dam/downloads/g0/express/services/surcharges/dhl_express_remote_areas.pdf) example of requirements from one company. Using that pdf i'd be adding the last two letters myself for my arithmetic